# jQuery - looking to show / hide toggle (using .previous) - where am I going wrong?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, closest, siblings

I am looking to do a simple show / hide toggle.

When you click the what is the "add" div, it should show the previous sibling. However, despite this seeming so simple, it won't work. I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

edit* removed part of my question that I resolved (I got the .hide() portion working), but still can't get the piece I mention above to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghnne/12/

```
<div class='sideRowStackedInputSideNarrow'>

    <div class='sideRowCreateAdditionalInput'></div>

    <div class='sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNext'>
        <div class='sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNextClose'></div>
    </div>

     <div class='sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNext'>
        <div class='sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNextClose'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='sideRowCreateAdd'></div>

</div>

$('.sideRowCreateAdd').click(function(){

        $(this).previous('.sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNext').show();

    });

    $('.sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNextClose').click(function(){

        $(this).closest('.sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNext').hide();

    });
```

Comment: include your html please

Comment: Included my html, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: first of all change hide into hide() . Its a method .http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Yup, was just editing my post to say I fixed that. Just typo on my part. I still can't get the part working though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/ghnne/15/ I think your typo mistakes make your jquery not working one for hide() and other one for prev , anyways its working now check posted url .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `.prev()` and *not* `.previous()`

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$('.sideRowCreateAdd').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('.sideRowCreateAdditionalInputNext').show();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghnne/16/

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I screwed that up. Thank you!